# Randomise posts from the retrieved 4

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a list of 4 posts from the category defined in my Wordpress loop, id like to be able to randomise them, just randomise the 4 that have already been retrieved (most recent), not 4 random from the entire category.

I've tried the following but simply shows 4 random posts from the category, doesn't randomise the first 4 which should be shown as they are the 4 most recent.

```
//get terms (category ids 11,2,33,34), then display one post in each term
$taxonomy = 'category';//  e.g. post_tag, category
$param_type = 'category__in'; //  e.g. tag__in, category__in
$term_args=array(
  'include' => '1459',
);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);

if ($terms) {
  foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $args=array(
      "$param_type" => array($term->term_id),
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 4,
      'orderby' => 'rand',
      'order' => 'DESC'
      );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 elements in array:

```
$categories = [
    [], [], [], []
];
```

To make it in random order, use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function

```
shuffle($categories); // modifies original array, returns true/false

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo 'WooHoo';
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on this any more please? I don't see how I have any type of array already. Pretty new to this sorry.

Comment: @JordanC26 you have 4 posts in `$terms` array, so do `shuffle($terms)` to get them in random order

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `'order' => 'DESC'`  part.

Comment: This wouldn't define it to randomise just the 4 most recent however. It would then display a random from throughout the entire category regardless if they were the latest 4 or not.